# Saving Base64 encoded CER file to a String

Tags: java, certificate, rsa, word-wrap

I am currently able to read a Key modulus from a cer file using this code, also found on StackOverflow:

```
X509Certificate cert = null;
String source = "src/testCer.cer";
InputStream fis = null;                 
ByteArrayInputStream bais = null;               


fis = new FileInputStream(source);              
byte value[] = new byte[fis.available()];       
fis.read(value);                                
bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(value);             
java.security.cert.CertificateFactory cf = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bais);    
RSAPublicKey pub = (RSAPublicKey) cert.getPublicKey();

System.out.println(pub.getModulus());
```

The .cer file looks like this: (certificate is an example Alice certificate found on the internet):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

A nicely Base64 Encoded wrapped text.

**My question:**

**How would I save this certificate to a String, and use that instead of reading the certificate from a file?**

So far I tried:

```
String cert_1= "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"
                + "MIIBuTCCASKgAwIBAgIQNdNhtuV5GbNHYZsf+LvM0zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAb"
                + "MRkwFwYDVQQDExBFZGlkZXYgU21va2VUZXN0MB4XDTA4MTExMjE5NTEzNVoXDTM5"
                + "MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQRWRpZGV2IFNtb2tlVGVzdDCBnzANBgkq"
                + "hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAm6zGzqxejwswWTNLcSsa7P8xqODspX9VQBuq"
                + "CBpT4S5AaO3/wkYQSKdI108pXH7Aue0e/ZOwgEEX1N6OaPQn7AmAB4uq1h+ffw+r"
                + "5W1RoTgQ0LNR64+7ywLjH8+wrb/lB6QV7s2SFUiWDeduVesvMJkWtZ5zzQyl3iUa"
                + "RKNHqnsCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQCZmj+pgRsN6HpoICawK3XXNAmi"
                + "cgfQkailX9akIjD3xSCwEQx4nG6tZjTz30u4NoSffW7pch58SxuZQDqW5NsJcQNq"
                + "Ngo/dMoqqpXdi2/0BYEcJ8pjsngrFm+fM2BnyGpXH7aWuKsWjVFGlWlF+yi8I35Q"
                + "8wFJt2Z/XGA7WWDjvw=="
                + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert_1.getBytes());
```

Which results in an error: *java.io.IOException: Incomplete data*.

fis.available also differes from the certificate loaded from file. (it is 2 shorter).
I am guessing this has to do with the WRAPPING. I am suspecting this because a .cer file does not work if the Header is not alone on the first line as seen in notepad, but does work otherwise.

Comment: Well for a start, your string doesn't have any line breaks... try putting `\n` *at least* at the end of the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` line and the one before `END CERTIFICATE`. I'd also strongly recommend *always* specifying an encoding when you call `toString`.

Comment: Jon Skeet: Putting it after BEGIN CERTIFICATE works perfectly. Can you please put it in an answer, so I can select the answer as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your string literal doesn't have any line breaks. To faithfully represent the original text, you'd need:

```
String cert_1= "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    + "MIIBuTCCASKgAwIBAgIQNdNhtuV5GbNHYZsf+LvM0zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAb\n"
    + "MRkwFwYDVQQDExBFZGlkZXYgU21va2VUZXN0MB4XDTA4MTExMjE5NTEzNVoXDTM5\n"
    + "MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQRWRpZGV2IFNtb2tlVGVzdDCBnzANBgkq\n"
    + "hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAm6zGzqxejwswWTNLcSsa7P8xqODspX9VQBuq\n"
    + "CBpT4S5AaO3/wkYQSKdI108pXH7Aue0e/ZOwgEEX1N6OaPQn7AmAB4uq1h+ffw+r\n"
    + "5W1RoTgQ0LNR64+7ywLjH8+wrb/lB6QV7s2SFUiWDeduVesvMJkWtZ5zzQyl3iUa\n"
    + "RKNHqnsCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQCZmj+pgRsN6HpoICawK3XXNAmi\n"
    + "cgfQkailX9akIjD3xSCwEQx4nG6tZjTz30u4NoSffW7pch58SxuZQDqW5NsJcQNq\n"
    + "Ngo/dMoqqpXdi2/0BYEcJ8pjsngrFm+fM2BnyGpXH7aWuKsWjVFGlWlF+yi8I35Q\n"
    + "8wFJt2Z/XGA7WWDjvw==\n"
    + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

... but you could probably get away with just making sure that the `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` and `END CERTIFICATE` markers are on their own lines:

```
String cert_1= "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
    + "MIIBuTCCASKgAwIBAgIQNdNhtuV5GbNHYZsf+LvM0zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADAb"
    + "MRkwFwYDVQQDExBFZGlkZXYgU21va2VUZXN0MB4XDTA4MTExMjE5NTEzNVoXDTM5"
    + "MTIzMTIzNTk1OVowGzEZMBcGA1UEAxMQRWRpZGV2IFNtb2tlVGVzdDCBnzANBgkq"
    + "hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAm6zGzqxejwswWTNLcSsa7P8xqODspX9VQBuq"
    + "CBpT4S5AaO3/wkYQSKdI108pXH7Aue0e/ZOwgEEX1N6OaPQn7AmAB4uq1h+ffw+r"
    + "5W1RoTgQ0LNR64+7ywLjH8+wrb/lB6QV7s2SFUiWDeduVesvMJkWtZ5zzQyl3iUa"
    + "RKNHqnsCAwEAATANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOBgQCZmj+pgRsN6HpoICawK3XXNAmi"
    + "cgfQkailX9akIjD3xSCwEQx4nG6tZjTz30u4NoSffW7pch58SxuZQDqW5NsJcQNq"
    + "Ngo/dMoqqpXdi2/0BYEcJ8pjsngrFm+fM2BnyGpXH7aWuKsWjVFGlWlF+yi8I35Q"
    + "8wFJt2Z/XGA7WWDjvw==\n"
    + "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";
```

I'd also recommend explicitly specifying the charset any time you convert between text and binary data:

```
fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert_1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```